# how recursion works in this code

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm trying to understand how recursion works. There are simple examples such as factorial and so on and I understand them clearly but I couldn't understand here how halfOne and halfTwo are assigned recursively. What is the order of call here and whats going on in this code? Appreciating for any help. Thank you in advance.

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    const int SIZE = 5;

    double average(int nums[], int left, int right, double len);

    int main()
    {
        int nums[SIZE];
        int left, right;
        double len; //If len was an int, the average would always be zero
        double avg = 0;

        //These are for testing
        long double testNum = 0;
        long double testAvg;

        //Populate the array with random integers from 1 - 100
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        {
            nums[i] = (rand() % 100) + 1;
            testNum = testNum + nums[i]; //For Testing
        }

        left = 0;
        right = SIZE - 1;
        len = right - left + 1; //For computing the average
        avg = average(nums, left, right, len);

        testAvg = testNum / SIZE; //To test my function
        cout << "Average from assignment: " << testAvg << endl;

        cout << "Average from function: " << avg << endl;

        int x;
        cin >> x;

        return 0;
    }


    //This function will find the average of all the numbers in an array
    //By summing together every number divided by the total len.
    //This works because (1 + 2 + 3)/3 is equal to (1/3) + (2/3) + (3/3)
    double average(int nums[], int left, int right, double len)
    {
        double halfOne, halfTwo;
        //This is the base case which will be evaluated
        if (left == right)
            return (nums[left] / len);

        //The array is split until it is of the size 1
        //And each element is evaluated with the base case
        halfOne = average(nums, left, (left + right) / 2, len);
        halfTwo = average(nums, (left + right + 2) / 2, right, len);

        //Each half is added together to get the final total average. 
        return (halfOne + halfTwo);
    }
```

Comment: Fire up a debugger ans step through it. Or use a piece of paper and trace it out.

Comment: I fired up it but really didn't understand it this is why I ask here

Comment: Use the box method for tracing recursive functions. https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2002/cmsc214/Tutorial/trace-recursion.html

Comment: I'll walk you through it because obviously your teacher did not: Traditionally recursive functions start with a stop condition from which they start re-cursing back to the original call. In this case the line `if(left == right)`. This function actually does nothing except divide the array in half until the line is true meaning it received single element . Once this is true it returns the average of the single value divided by the total length and while returning from each call, adds the result from one half to the result from the other half (possible because of what was explained in comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should build the recursion tree yourself, by hand to really understand the problem, for example you have an array [2, 4, 6, 0, 1]: 
Len = 5, left = 0 and right = 4, then you call average, since left =! right, the array is split in two, then the function call itself twice, once with left = 0 and right = left+right/2 = 2 and the other half  is called with left = 3 and right = 4. 
None of these two calls fulfill the condition right=left so it gets called again twice for each function with (Left = 0, right = 1), (left = 2, right = 2) and the other (left = 3, right = 3) (left = 4, right =4). Except for the case (left = 0 and right =1) each gets calculated since left = right, then the ones that are calculated return: num[left = right]/len and the case left = 0 and right = 1 gets split and returns the case (left = 0, right = 0) and (left = 1, right =1). Then each case is returned and each half is summed and what you are left with  is the sum of each value divided by the length.

So to sum up this here are the steps the function takes:

Average([2,4,6,0,1]) => returns (Average([2,4,6]) + average([0,1])) => returns (average([2,4])+average([6]))+(average([0])+average([1]))=>((average([2])+average([4]))+(6/5))+((0/5)+(1/5))=>(((2/5)+(4/5))+ (6/5))+(1/5)=>(6/5+6/5)+1/5=>13/5 and voilá.

This is a really weird way to do this even for functional programming, a more common way would be:(In pseudo code)

```
double Average(nums[], left, right,len)
{
if left == right
  return num[left]/len
return average(nums,left,left,len)+average(nums,left+1,right,len)
}
```

Comment: Your explanation is very good but the function you gave is Sum not Average :)

Comment: You're right! I missed it. Thanks, now I think it's right.

Comment: Crystal-like clear. Thank you such a great explanation.